# Print button to print a attached image

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add a print button in my webpage. upon clicking the print icon, it should automatically start print the attached image

How can i achieve this?

Comment: That could work if you simply press on picture. Is that enough?

Comment: No, I don't want to add the image. Only the word print like <a href="image.jpg"> print</a>

Comment: user have to click the "print" to print the image

Comment: http://www.codescratcher.com/javascript/print-image-using-javascript/#comment-762

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open new window using `window.open`.
2. Write to it the `img` tag.
3. Once the image was loaded, print the document using `window.print()`.
4. Close the window using `window.close()`

You can do this with code like this:

```js
function printImg(url) {
  var win = window.open('');
  win.document.write('<img src="' + url + '" onload="window.print();window.close()" />');
  win.focus();
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCYTd.jpg" />
<button onclick="printImg('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCYTd.jpg')">Print</button>
```

http://jsbin.com/qaruze/edit?html,js