# How to print a png/jpg file from HTML/PHP page?

Tags: php, html, image, printing

I'm trying to print a PNG/JPG file, which is in my website directory, from an HTML/PHP page. This image is already generated and I need to print it selecting the directory path and the file name.
Using the

```html
<button onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
```

I'm getting the printing of the whole web page (included attributes, links, etc.)
Is there a method to send to the printer only the file images/image.png?
Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print button to print a attached image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681922/print-button-to-print-a-attached-image)

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use CSS specific for printing - that way round you can style how the page will look like once you print it. Start by adding this to your HEAD tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="my_print.css" />
```

A good tutorial can be found here - https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/

Answer (score 0):

open one popup. By giving the image id to print. you can print out.

```
function printImg() {
popup = window.open();
popup.document.getElementById("imageid");
popup.focus(); //required for IE
popup.print();
}
```